# hdfs plain text write to hbase,Output directory not set

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

In Map I read Hdfs file update to Hbase,

Version：hadoop 2.5.1 hbase 1.0.0

Exception as follows :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not set.
```

maybe there is something wrong with

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(TableOutputFormat.class);
```

this line prompt：

```
The method setOutputFormatClass(Class<? extends OutputFormat>) in the type Job is not applicable for the arguments (Class<TableOutputFormat>)
```

codes as follows:

```
public class HdfsAppend2HbaseUtil extends Configured implements Tool{

    public static class HdfsAdd2HbaseMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>{

        public void map(Text ikey, Text ivalue, Context context) 
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String oldIdList = HBaseHelper.getValueByKey(ikey.toString());

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(oldIdList);
            String newIdList = ivalue.toString();
            sb.append("\t" + newIdList);

            Put p = new Put(ikey.toString().getBytes());
            p.addColumn("idFam".getBytes(), "idsList".getBytes(), sb.toString().getBytes());
            context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(), p);

        }

    }

    public int run(String[] paths) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "master,salve1");
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf,"AppendToHbase");
        job.setJarByClass(cn.edu.hadoop.util.HdfsAppend2HbaseUtil.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);

        job.setMapperClass(HdfsAdd2HbaseMapper.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        job.setOutputFormatClass(TableOutputFormat.class); 

        job.getConfiguration().set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, "reachableTable");

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(paths[0]));


        job.setOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Put.class);


        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Append Start: ");

        long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long time2;
        String[] pathsStr = {Const.TwoDegreeReachableOutputPathDetail};

        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new HdfsAppend2HbaseUtil(), pathsStr);
        time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Append Cost " + "\t" + (time2-time1)/1000 +" s");

        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the output directory where it is to write the output like you gave for input path.
Mention it like this.

```
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(<output path>));
```

Comment: In fact , I don't need a output directory, I want to update the data in Hbase. I am not very clear about how to update , if U know , please share to me thank U very much.

Answer (score 0):

At last , I know why,just as I supposed there is something wrong with:

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(TableOutputFormat.class);
```

this line prompt：

```
The method setOutputFormatClass(Class<? extends OutputFormat>) in the type Job is not applicable for the arguments (Class<TableOutputFormat>)
```

In fact here we need import

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat
```

not to import

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat
```

the former extends from org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat

see:
https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapred/TableOutputFormat.html

and the later extends from 
    org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.OutputFormat

see:

https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableOutputFormat.html

**At last Thank U all very much!!!**